# Finding a next lowest number from a List in python

Tags: python, algorithm, window, sliding

I have a list of arrays as follows:
Array =[3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3]

example:
Value = 3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3

valley/Peak = v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p, v, p,v

[image]

Comment: Indexes in Python start with 0, not 1.

Comment: Why not try a loop with an if statement? (also, FYI indexes start from 0 in lists in Python, so the value 3 is actually at index 0)

Comment: yea it starts with index 0

Comment: (In [3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1], the next lower number from index 0 is at index 2, while the nearest *lowest* number is at index 5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## logic

assign the index to start from

assign the value of the starting index

make a loop starting from the starting index to the end of the loop

in the loop check if current number is smaller than the starting target

[slice](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp) the list to create the result sublist

## code

```
array = [3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3]

start_index = 0  # the index to start from

# start_index = int(input("Enter the index to start from: ")) # to take this a step further, you could ask the user for the index to start from

target = array[start_index]  # the number in the starting index

for i in range(start_index, len(array)):  # loop from the start index till the end
    if array[i] < target:  # if the current number is smaller than my traget
        # split the list from the start index to the current index (+1 because the slice is not inclusive)
        print(array[start_index:i+1])
        break
    if i == len(array)-1:  # if we reached the end of the list
        print('fail')  # print the rest of the list
```

## input

`start_index = 0`

`array = [3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3]`

## output

`[3, 6, 5, 7, 2]`

Comment: Yeah It is but the main finish output has been updated above

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Ransom & SA.93 suggested, indexing in python starts from 0. Maybe you are more familiar with R... :) For your solution, try this;

```
def next_lowest_num(Array,num):
    lst = []
    for i in Array[Array.index(num):]:
        if i >= num:
            lst.append(i)
        else:
            lst.append(i)
            break
    return lst

print(next_lowest_num(Array=[3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3],num=3))
print(next_lowest_num(Array=[3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3],num=5))

# Output
[3, 6, 5, 7, 2]
[5, 7, 2]
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Yeah It is   but the main finish output has been updated above